# Ruby: Adding an Empty Array to a Dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, database, dictionary

I am trying to create an array within a dictionary as follows.

What I would like to have:

```
"Message": {
            [    
               "0": "This is a message"
            ]  
           }
```

What I have now:

```
"Message": {
               "0": ["This is a message"
               ]
           }
```

I am using the following code to initialize the Message dictionary, and the array within it.

```
  if not_found
    convoNum = 0
    arrayIndex = 0
    sessions["total"] = (sessions["total"].to_i + 1).to_s
    sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"] = {"arrayIndex"=>"#{arrayIndex}", "convoNum"=>"0"}
    sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"] = {}
    sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"][sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"].length] = []
  end
```

I am having trouble in rendering my desired layout. Simply adding `sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"] = {[]}` causes my database to crash upon initiation. Any help in getting to the first layout would be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense.  Elements of a hash (or dictionary) have a key and a value.  You want a value with no key.

Comment: You don't happen to be a Python programmer do you? Clues: over-reliance on data structures, the term "dictionary". Modeling your domain using a small class would simplify the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "Modeling your domain using a small class would simplify the code"?

Comment: Instead of a Hash called `sessions`, have an instance of a class called `Sessions`, with attributes `total` and `users`, and methods to help you build this structure.  Have other small objects you add to it like `Message` that help as well.  Makes testing a breeze and whoever inherits this code will thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have (Array cannot have key value pairs)

```
"Message": {
            [    
               "0": "This is a message"
            ]  
           }
```

You can have

```
"Message": {
               "0": "This is a message",
               "1": "Next message"
           }
```

You can initialize it like this

```
sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"] = {}
```

And add values like

```
sessions["users"]["#{sessions["total"]}"]["Message"]["0"] = "This is a message"
```

Comment: Right! I just want a way of separating elements within "Messages". I can have a Messages array and append multiple dictionaries to it, right?

Comment: @user3694391. yes. you can have `"Messages" : ["This is a message"]`

Answer (score 1):

When you say this:

```
{
  [    
     "0": "This is a message"
  ]  
}
```

That is not valid Ruby.  You're putting a key/value pair in an array, that doesn't make any sense.